# On differentiability of a certain function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ be real-valued continuous function on the real line satisfying
$$\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\textrm{ card}(f^{-1}(\{y\}))<\infty$$
where card denotes the cardinality of set. This means there exists certain $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ contains at most $N$ elements for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Now I want to show $f'$ exists almost everywhere (with respect to canonical Lebesgue measure on the real line).

I guess the set containing points that cannot be differentiated should be at most countable but have no idea of where to start. Any hint shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would suffice to show that there are countably many disjoint segments, covering the entire line, such that $f$ is monotonic on each segment. I'm not quite there, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $N(f,y):=\operatorname{card}(f^{-1}(\{y\}))$ is called a [Banach indicatrix](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Banach_indicatrix). 
There is a nice answer to the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68635/banach-indicatrix-function). Using its results we know that $N(f,\cdot)$ is measurable, but from assumption $N(f,\cdot)$ is uniformly bounded, hence integrable. From the same answer we conclude that $f$ is of bounded variation, therefore differentiable almost everywhere.