# Represent total variation of continuous function by integration of counting function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, let $M(y)$ be the number of points $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=y$. prove that $M$ is Borel masurable and $\int M(y)dy$ equals the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$

This is an exercise in 'real analysis for graduate students'(Richard.F.Bass)

At first time, I thought  $M(y)=\mu(\{x \mid f(x)=y\})$ where $\mu$ is counting measure. But I cannot find the relation between Borel measurability and $\mu(\{x \mid f(x)=y\})$

Is there anyone would help me?

Comment: This an exercise from W. Rudin book "Real and Complex analysis" (exercise 8.22) and there in this book is an hint how to prove it.

Comment: I can't find exercise 8.22 in the book. Isn't it 2nd edition? If you have the book now, can you let me know the hint? Please

Comment: The hint is; "The theorem is obvious for functions whose graphs are union of line segments. But every continuous function can by approximated by such functions"

Comment: Thank you . Now I can prove it with your hint

Comment: If you use simple functions (step functions), $M(y)$ will be $+\infty$ at finitely many points, and zero elsewhere. I don't think this will work. For example, if $f(x)=x$, then $M(y)=1$, there is no way you will reach this with a function taking only the values $+\infty$ and $0$. I believe Rudin means you should use functions which are locally linear (resp. locally affine)

Comment: Here is some idea (just an idea). Fix a $y$ and for now assume that it is finite. place tiny open sets around these points. Show that for z near y these balls also cover preimage of z. By taking limit you end up proving semi-continuity of the function.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Banach indicatrix Theorem, which he proved in 1925:

[1] S. Banach, "Sur les lignes rectifiables et les surfaces dont l'aire est finie" Fund. Math. , 7 (1925) pp. 225–236
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm7/fm7116.pdf

An exposition in English of Banach's proof is given in

[Banach Indicatrix Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68635/banach-indicatrix-function)

Generalizations are in

[2] S.M. Lozinskii, "On the Banach indicatrix" Vestnik Leningrad. Univ. Math. Mekh. Astr. , 7 : 2 pp. 70–87 (In Russian)

[3] https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-27/issue-2/Generalization-of-the-Banach-Indicatrix-Theorem/rae/1212412867.full

Comment: Great answer! Please, the Bass' book asks for $f$ continuous, but I must also have $f$ of bounded variation, or not? Thank you so much!

Comment: If $f$ is of unbounded variation, then the theorem still holds, and $\int M(y) \,dy=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you really much